# URLDownloadToFile Error: INET_E_SECURITY_PROBLEM

Tags: excel, vba

I'm modifying code to download multiple files via Excel VBA.
The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

'API function declaration for both 32 and 64bit Excel.
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
                                    (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                                    ByVal szURL As String, _
                                    ByVal szFileName As String, _
                                    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                                    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
                            (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                            ByVal szURL As String, _
                            ByVal szFileName As String, _
                            ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                            ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If



Sub DownloadFiles()

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'The macro loops through all the URLs (column C) and downloads the files at the specified folder.
    'The characters after the last "/" of the URL string are used to create the file path.
    'If the file is downloaded successfully an OK will appear in column D (otherwise an ERROR value).
    'The code is based on API function URLDownloadToFile, which actually does all the work.
     'Written By:    Christos Samaras
     'Date:          02/11/2013
     'Last Update:   06/06/2015
     'E-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
     'Site:          https://myengineeringworld.net/////
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim sh                  As Worksheet
    Dim DownloadFolder      As String
    Dim LastRow             As Long
    Dim SpecialChar()       As String
    Dim SpecialCharFound    As Double
    Dim FilePath            As String
    Dim i                   As Long
    Dim j                   As Integer
    Dim Result              As Long
    Dim CountErrors         As Long

    'Disable screen flickering.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Set the worksheet object to the desired sheet.
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'An array with special characters that cannot be used for naming a file.
    SpecialChar() = Split(" / : * ? " & Chr$(34) & " < > |", " ")

    'Find the last row.
     With sh
        .Activate
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Check if the download folder exists.
    DownloadFolder = sh.Range("B4")
    On Error Resume Next
    If Dir(DownloadFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "The folder's path is incorrect!", vbCritical, "Folder's Path Error"
        sh.Range("B4").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Check if there is at least one URL.
    If LastRow < 8 Then
        MsgBox "You did't enter a single URL!", vbCritical, "No URL Error"
        sh.Range("C8").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Clear the results column.
    sh.Range("D8:D" & LastRow).ClearContents

    'Add the backslash if doesn't exist.
    If Right(DownloadFolder, 1) <> "" Then
        DownloadFolder = DownloadFolder & ""
    End If

    'Counting the number of files that will not be downloaded.
    CountErrors = 0

    'Save the internet files at the specified folder of your hard disk.
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 8 To LastRow

        'Find the characters after the last "/" of the URL.
        With WorksheetFunction
            FilePath = Mid(sh.Cells(i, 3), .Find("*", .Substitute(sh.Cells(i, 3), "/", "*", Len(sh.Cells(i, 3)) - _
                        Len(.Substitute(sh.Cells(i, 3), "/", "")))) + 1, Len(sh.Cells(i, 3)))
        End With

        'Check if the file path contains a special/illegal character.
        For j = LBound(SpecialChar) To UBound(SpecialChar)
            SpecialCharFound = InStr(1, FilePath, SpecialChar(j), vbTextCompare)
            'If an illegal character is found substitute it with a "-" character.
            If SpecialCharFound > 0 Then
                FilePath = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FilePath, SpecialChar(j), "-")
            End If
        Next j

        'Create the final file path.
        FilePath = DownloadFolder & FilePath

        'Check if the file path exceeds the maximum allowable characters.
        If Len(FilePath) > 255 Then
            sh.Cells(i, 4) = "ERROR"
            sh.Cells(i, 2) = "ERROR1"
            CountErrors = CountErrors + 1
        End If

        'If the file path is valid, save the file into the selected folder.
        If UCase(sh.Cells(i, 4)) <> "ERROR" Then

            'Try to download and save the file.
            Result = URLDownloadToFile(0, sh.Cells(i, 3), FilePath, 0, 0)

            'Check if the file downloaded successfully and exists.
            If Result = 0 And Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                'Success!
                sh.Cells(i, 4) = "OK"
                sh.Cells(i, 2) = Result & "&" & FilePath & "&" & vbDirectory
            Else
                'Error!
                sh.Cells(i, 4) = "ERROR"
                sh.Cells(i, 2) = Result & "&" & FilePath & "&" & vbDirectory
                CountErrors = CountErrors + 1
            End If

        End If

    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Inform the user that macro finished successfully or with errors.
    If CountErrors = 0 Then
        'Success!
        If LastRow - 7 = 1 Then
            MsgBox "The file was successfully downloaded!", vbInformation, "Done"
        Else
            MsgBox LastRow - 7 & " files were successfully downloaded!", vbInformation, "Done"
        End If
    Else
        'Error!
        If CountErrors = 1 Then
            MsgBox "There was an error with one of the files!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
            MsgBox "There was an error with " & CountErrors & " files!", vbCritical, "Error"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This code downloads most files just fine, but I ran across issues when trying to download from `SPP(Southwest Power Pool)`'s API. For Example:

https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/da-lmp-by-location?path=%2F2018%2F11%2FDA-LMP-MONTHLY-SL-201811.csv

This file or any similar file that I try to download from this api is identified and downloaded just fine by any browser or download manager, but `URLDownloadToFile` reports an error and does not download the file. It downloads files from other sources successfully
[image: Example Screenshot]

My knowledge of coding allowed me to track down the error/return code, which is reported in column B by the following bit of code:

```
sh.Cells(i, 2) = Result & "&" & FilePath & "&" & vbDirectory
```

To my understanding, this indicates `INET_E_SECURITY_PROBLEM` with return code of `-2146697202`.
Beyond Identifying the error, I am out of my depth.
Assistance in figuring out how to get past this major roadblock would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you tried [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52245239/6241235) download? How is that API in terms of speed/size of files?

Comment: I have not. I'm quite new to VBA and it'll take me a bit to understand what's happening in the function and implement it. I will get to it now.
As for the API speed, chrome was downloading at about 5MB/s. The monthly datasets I am trying to download are about 20MB each

Comment: I did a quick and dirty version of the function you provided:
`Set wb = Workbooks.Open(DownloadFile("D:\Project\Database\SPP\", "https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/da-lmp-by-location?path=%2F2018%2F11%2FDA-LMP-MONTHLY-SL-201811.csv"))`

resulted in a download failed message

Comment: while debugging I found:
`  - : ResponseStream :  : Variant/<Unsupported object type>`

Comment: This is a good post +1